# Analogue of OpenFileDialog for wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

In OpenFileDialog there is a button for creation of a new folder at pushing on which, there is a creation of a new folder, assignment to it to a name and setting of focus for renaming. How can I implement it in my program?

Comment: And Why do you want to do exactly that's already been done?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

WPF does have an [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) class you can use, just like Windows Forms.  It's in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace.  It contains this same feature.